# Random number function that factors into account Cumulative Frequency

Tags: math, statistics, frequency

The [census dataset for last name](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/dist.all.last) and first name occurrences provides `cumulative frequency` and `frequency`. How do I go about getting a random name with the likelyhood of it being chosen that of the occurrence in the real world?

Answer (score 6):

Just generate a random real number in the 0-100 range and look for the corresponding entry in the cumulative frequency dataset.

Example, say your random number gives `x = 19.41`. Look into the table (sorted by cumulative frequencies) and locate the first one that has a value greater or equal than `x`

```
WALLACE        0.081 19.315    106
WOODS          0.080 19.395    107
COLE           0.080 19.476    108
WEST           0.080 19.555    109
JORDAN         0.078 19.634    110
```

in this example, you obtain 'COLE'

Comment: Would it be greater than or equal to X? The first name is Smith with a cumulative frequency of 1.006, if I get 0.6584 how would I go about doing it?

Comment: It's also confusing because in the linked dataset, the max value for cumfreq is 90.483, not 100. That means that for all random numbers between 90.483-100.000 (roughly 10%) of the time, I should show AARDEMA? That can't be right. I've never even meet a single AARDEMA in my life.

Comment: @Evan The last 10% consists of names that are so rare, that putting them all in the list would take gigabytes to download. You just got the 90.483% most frequent names.